# Android change referer in Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, image, loader, universal, referer

I have a problem with download images in Android using Universal Image Loader library. I am sure that it is caused by I need to change the referer. How can I set the referer in Universal Image Loader library?

This is a code into my Adapter

```
ImageView imagenPersona = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgPersona);     
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(activity));
imageLoader.displayImage(item.getUrlImagenPersona(), imagenPersona);
```

Comment: Could you show us some code, please?

Comment: Here is my code. It is into my Adapter. I would like to change the url referer for obtein an Internet image.                                             ImageView         imagenPersona = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgPersona);
     
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
  imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(activity));
  imageLoader.displayImage(item.getUrlImagenPersona(), imagenPersona);

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18079066/edit) and add your code instead of a comment. It is much more readable then.